# API connection issue in docker zabbix appliance

Tags: python, docker, zabbix

i have installed docker desktop in windows system and installed zabbix docker appliance for testing.
with the zabbix appliance i am able to login into the front end of zabbix with 127.0.0.1/zabbix. But when i'm using the same credentials with python API i am unable to login.

i'm using below code to connect other zabbix instances whihc is working fine, when i'm connecting the docker appliance its not working.

```
from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI

zapi = ZabbixAPI("http://127.0.0.1/zabbix/")
zapi.login("Admin", "zabbix")
print("Connected to Zabbix API Version %s" % zapi.api_version())
```

Comment: Can you provide with the error that you're getting?

Comment: requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://127.0.0.1/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php

Comment: So the connection to your dockerized zabbix does work but it's missing the `api_jsonrpc.php` file. Is it possible that you're missing some plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be a path error, use `zapi = ZabbixAPI("http://127.0.0.1/")`

Comment: That is right. The documentation/screenshot mentioned the URL with `/zabbix` but actually it is not needed.